# Search static data from array based on route variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to search for a specific object in an array that has a unique slug that matches a variable in an array.
I am receiving an error when trying to use the switchmap without .valueChanges at the end of the return statement below, but I receive an error when using the valuechanges as well saying that it doesn't exist on "type 'void'".

Component

```
post$;
  constructor(private nrs: NewsroomService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.post$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap(params => {
        const post = params.get('slug');
        return this.nrs.postSearch(post).valueChanges();
      })
    );
  }
```

Here's the function from in the service:

```
postSearch(slug: string) {
    var __FOUND = -1;
        for(var i=0; i<this.posts.length; i++) {
            if(this.posts[i].postURL == slug) {
                // __FOUND is set to the index of the element
                __FOUND = i;
                break;
            }
        }
  }
```

I wasn't quite sure where to go from here in trying to resolve this.

Comment: `valueChanges()` is not something that exists on just any value. `postSearch()` does not return an `Observable`, let alone anything exposing to `valueChanges()`. Also `postSearch()` does not return anything at all. I'd start with first having `postSearch()` return something, anything. Then, if you are using `switchMap`, you will need to return an `Observable` from with the `switchMap`. That being said, `switchMap` would not be needed if you aren't dealing with an inner `Observable` such as `HttpClient` call, you may be able to use operator `map` simply instead.

Comment: I didn't catch that it didn't return something! I'll give this a go! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating the post component to this:

```
post$: any;
  constructor(private nrs: NewsroomService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.post$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
        map(params => {
          const post = params.get('slug');
          return this.nrs.postSearch(post);
        })
      );
    }
```

and changing the service function to this:

```
postSearch(slug: string) {
    var __FOUND = -1;
        for(var i=0; i<this.posts.length; i++) {
            if(this.posts[i].postURL == slug) {
                // __FOUND is set to the index of the element
                __FOUND = i;
                return this.posts[__FOUND];
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: You can't really return from a `for` loop (or shouldn't), try something like [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead. `return this.posts.find(post => post.postURL === slug);`

Comment: Alright. I only did that because my dataset is a small, static, array of post objects. I'll give that a go to make it more scale-able though.